# How can I get access to Vodapay for testing purposes as a developer?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I am a developer working on the mini programs platform. I need access to the Vodapay app but I cannot find it on both the app store for iOS and the play store for Android. How can I get access to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is scheduled to launch sometime in August, that is why it is not available on the app store or google play store. To get access to the test version of the app, send an email to [miniprogramsupport@vodacom.co.za](http://mailto:miniprogramsupport@vodacom.co.za) . You will need to provide the following:

1. Name
2. Surname
3. Mini program you are working on
4. Platform you want access to: (For iOS, send associated apple ID, for Android, send email address used on google account found on the device)